# Setting Contact from Map.get() Returning Null - Debug Shows Contact

Tags: apex, case, map, contact

I have a Map that stores cases and existing contacts.

I am populating the map and confirming so with debug logs.

All of the debug logs show there is a returned Contact record when I use the .get method, however when I set the returned Contact from .get method to a contact it returns null.

What am I overlooking?

```
if (thisCase.ContactId == null) {

    //RETURNS: USER_DEBUG [XX]|DEBUG|caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase): Contact:{Id=0033I00000HXXXXXXX, Name=John Doe, Email=john.doe@website.com, RecordTypeId=0123I000000XXXXXXX}
    system.debug('caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase): ' + caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase));

    //If case is in existing contact map, add contact to map of insert
    if (caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase) != null) {

        //RETURNS: USER_DEBUG [XX]|DEBUG|caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase): Contact:{Id=0033I00000HXXXXXXX, Name=John Doe, Email=john.doe@website.com, RecordTypeId=0123I000000XXXXXXX}
        system.debug('caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase): ' + caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase));

        thisCase.ContactId = caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase).Id;
        Contact thisContact = new Contact();

        thisContact = caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase);

        //RETURNS: NULL
        system.debug('thisContact: ' + thisContact);

        mapOfCaseAndContact.put(thisCase, thisContact);    
    }
```

Comment: so much better to name your maps that follow patterns such as `contactsByCaseId` so it is super clear to you what the key of the map is and what the value of the map is. See Lightning Enterprise Architecture book by Andrew Fawcett for best practice naming conventions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the look of it, your Map is a `Map<Case, Contact>`

when you modify `thisCase` with

```
thisCase.ContactId = caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase).Id;
```

you make a modification on `thisCase`, so the next `caseExistingContactMap.get(thisCase)` you do, `thisCase` is different than the original and it does find the contact anymore.

Have you tried doing a `Map</*Case*/Id, Contact>` so you have a "constant" key that you can always use?